# Media-Queries won't work on anything (Flex-Box)

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

I'm trying to do this task for Job Interview and the media queries just won't work.

Tried changing various settings, which worked in the past, tried on multiple selectors, nothing helps

Here's my code-pen: https://codepen.io/Orpeq/pen/dLWEZr

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .slider__text {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: 3rem; } }
```

Comment: did you try with just `@media (max-width: 700px)`?

Comment: Yes, nothing changes.

Comment: Okay. Can you provide more code from your css file? Also are you using any preprocessor like Less or Sass?

Comment: I've provided You with whole codepen :)
https://codepen.io/Orpeq/pen/dLWEZr

Comment: I pasted your code in VSCode and tried to format it, and the formatter gave me an error saying there were unexpected closing anchor tags `</a>`. I think this is what's causing the problem. Take a look at Line 38 and Line 72 of your HTML code

Comment: I've got it working, thanks to You Ajay! Huge thanks! <3
I've updated my code pen.